# jQuery slide right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a wordpress purchased theme I want to change the behavior of JavaScript when page is loaded or loading

currently my title animate from top to bottom i want to change that behavior on run time.

you can see it here

http://wordpress.p198800.webspaceconfig.de/

I have tried to do it

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myFix { bottom: 0 !important; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFix() {

        $("#slidecaption").addClass("myFix");

        $("#slidecaption").css("marginRight", "0").animate({
            marginRight: "+=1000"
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They jQuery expressions are correct, however if you never actually call `myFix()` that code will never run.

A common approach around executing functionality autonomously is the SEAF(self executing anonymous function):

```
(function myFix() {
  $("#slidecaption").addClass("myFix");

  $("#slidecaption").css("marginRight", "0").animate({
    marginRight: "+=1000"
  }
})();
```

Wrapping a function like so will cause it to run without ever being explicitly invoked.

This specific example is technically not an anonymous, but is assuming that you intend to be able call `myFix()` at some other time while still wanting it to run itself.

If you don't need to invoke it and simply need the jQuery rules applied, take the function out of the picture all together:

```
<script>
  $("#slidecaption").addClass("myFix");

  $("#slidecaption").css("marginRight", "0").animate({
    marginRight: "+=1000"
  }
</script>
```

More here: http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Im assuming here that a failed invocation of `myFix()` is the problem. If you do have that function bound to some event not shown here, please update your post with the big picture.

The other alternative is that the jQuery selectors aren't finding anything because of state of the DOM when these rules are being applied. Try:

```
console.log($('#slidecaption'));
```

to see if jQuery even returns anything. If it doesn't, then that is most likely your problem ;)